# How to run Google Apps script from HtmlUnit?

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script, htmlunit, google-sites

I have a link in a Google Sites page that runs a Google Apps script. It works fine when I manually click the link in Firefox.

Everything seems to work OK when I do the same using HtmlUnit. With HtmlUnit I can sign in (have to be signed in when running Google Apps scripts), get to the Web page, identify the link and click it, but the script does not run.

The guts of the code is straightforward:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://sites.google.com/site/mywebpage");
HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByName("MyAnchor");
anchor.click();
```

So what is missing, or what I am doing wrong?

I created the original link in the Web page with:

```
&lt;a href="/macros/sites?action=run&amp;lib=094bahv51120b3d65&amp;funcName=MyFunctionName" name="MyAnchor"&gt;Click here to run function&lt;/a&gt;
```

On saving the Web page edit, Google Sites automatically changed this to:

```
&lt;a href="#" name="MyAnchor" class="apps-script-run-link" id="ACiQKe2HyNeo..etc...01120b3d65#MyFunctionName"&gt;Click here to run function&lt;/a&gt;
```

Is `click()` not working because it acts on the href attribute that is now just "#" instead of the link definition?
Or does HtmlUnit's language support for JavaScript (Mozilla Rhino) not execute the Javascript correctly to process the clicked link (meaning that I need to replace Rhino with something that does recognised the Javascript in a Google Sites Web page)?
Or some other basic mistake I have made?

I am lost, so any help much appreciated!!

**UPDATE**

I followed your suggestion, Rodney, and found that the issue was not logging off Google sites. Using HtmlUnit to click on the 'Sign Out' link after clicking the link to execute the script, makes the script run OK. The only problem is it brings up the following error (which doesn't stop the script running):

> SEVERE: Job run failed with unexpected
>   RuntimeException:
>   TypeError: Cannot
>   set property "innerHTML" of null to
>   "Finished script: Finished script
>   MyFunctionName"

**UPDATE 2**

Have now solved this prob too. There was insufficient time to allow the script to complete before going on to sign-out. Adding this fixed it:

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
```

Many thanks for your help, Rodney - and Naveen for the good edit!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about calling a contained  Google Apps Script in old Google Sites, but the old Google Sites are now deprecated and the new Google Sites doesn't support contained scripts.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit has rather good Javascript support, so I doubt that's the issue.

How do you know the script hasn't run?   Or better, how would you know, from an HtmlUnit point-of-view, if the script has run successfully?   When you click the link in FF, you presumably see something happen.  You are relying on human vision and a browser meant for human use.  With HtmlUnit, you need to instruct your *code* to "see" the same result, whether by examining the subsequent DOM tree, or handling a popup, or whatever is needed.  It's a bit of a shift in thinking.

What does your script do?  Manipulate the content of the page?  Open a dialog?  Redirect to another page?   Some things HtmlUnit will handle automatically, and some (like opening dialogs) need handlers defined.

Comment: Yes, the script modifies the content of another Web page. It is easy to check whether the script ran from HtmlUnit by viewing the page in Firefox after the event. Is there any way to know what click() in HtmlUnit did other than inspecting the return  from the click() function which is the page jumped to by the link? Since click() only fires the script function, the returned Web page is the same as the current one, so this doesn't tell me much about what happened. Do you think I need some extra handlers defined to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Ah... "the returned Web page is the same as the current one" isn't quite correct.   It's the same instance of "HtmlPage" but its content will have been updated by any Javascript on the page, if your click() JS code does in fact change the page DOM.  At worst, call asXml() on the page object before and after calling click(); ideally you traverse the DOM looking for specific changes.

Comment: The script changes the content on a different page, not the page where the link running the script is (could that be important?). This wouldn't stop me in HtmlUnit going to that page and checking the content as you suggest, but how could it have changed anything since isn't the proof me manually browsing in Firefox later on and finding nothing changed? Or is something more complex happening here, with HtmlUnit in fact making the change, but it somehow not getting recorded correctly server side? Do you think your asXml() test is worth doing anyway?

Comment: It changes something on another page?  Sorry, missed that. Just "browse" that page using HtmlUnit and look for the change.  Exactly the same process as you'd do manually, you just do it in code.